# How do I set ROIs in OpenCV for face then mouth detection in video feeds?

Tags: opencv

We are using OpenCV for our project, and we plan to detect the face, then use that created rectangle as our ROI, then detect the mouth there. How do we set the ROI for videos? We searched how, but could only find answers for still images. We would like to set our ROI to the lower 1/3 or lower half of the detected face.

"haarcascade_mcs_mouth.xml" is used, but the rectangle is placed in the wrong spot. The mouth is detected near the right eyebrow.

Comment: Can you provide some example code showing exactly what you are doing and where it doesn't do what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Then you could first restrict the mouth cascade search in the bottom face region you have already detected.

Answer (score 1):

For image and videos, the process is same.
And if the rectangle is in wrong place, then you probably doing mistake in finding the points of mouth with the respect of frame.
Actually 
**`mouth_cascade.detectMultiScale(faces, mouth);`**
will give you co-ordinates ** w.r.t face**. So, when you are defining points for the co-ordinates of mouth then you must ensure adding co-ordinates of face.
Ex.
`mouth_cascade.detectMultiScale(faces[j], mouth);
for( size_t i=0; i < mouth.size(); i+++
{`
    `Point pt1( faces[j].x + mouth[i].x, faces[j].y + mouth[i].y);`
    `Point pt2( pt1.x + mouth[i].width, pt1.y + mouth[i].height);`
    `rectangle( frame, pt2, pt1, cvScalar(0, 0, 0, 255), 1, 8, 0);
}`
I hope I am clear with my view.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your code, as it's a bit confusing what the actual problem here is.

There is no difference in setting ROI for video or for a picture, for a video you will simply have a loop, where the Mat frame is continually updated. (I'm assuming you're using the C++ API and not the C API).

As for how to create a ROI in the bottom half of the face, take a look at this [tutorial](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html#cascade-classifier) (which btw uses video) and the [cv::detectMultiScale()](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html?highlight=haar%20cascades) function.

If you look in the tutorial, you'll see that they create the face ROI like so:

```
Mat faceROI = frame_gray( faces[i] );
```

If you look at faces, you see that it's a std::vector< Rect >, so faces[i] is a Rect containing the face detected by face_cascade.detectMultiScale( ... ).
So instead of creating the faceROI directly using that Rect, use a different Rect that only contains the lower half. Take a look at what a [cv::Rect](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=rect_#Rect_) is, and you'll find it is defined by the Rect.x and Rect.y coordinates of the top-left corner, and then by it's Rect.width and Rect.height. So create the ROI accordingly:

```
Rect tmp = faces[i]; //the Rect you want is the same as the original Rect
tmp.y = faces[i].y+faces[i].height/2; //except that it starts from half the face downwards (note that in image coordinates, origin is the topleft corner, and y increases downwards.
Mat faceROI = frame_gray(tmp);
```